# Inject metadata or text into WMV with PHP on Linux

Tags: php, linux, video, metadata, wmv

I run a website which serves videos to monthly subscribers who can download them. The majority of the videos are WMV and MP4. Is there a PHP or Linux library which would inject metadata or text into the video files without re-encoding the entire file?

My problem is that the videos are pirated and shared on other sites; we are losing money. So, I want to inject the downloader's username so that we can catch the pirates.

I cannot have the movies being re-rendendered/re-encoded for every download because it would put a lot of stress on the server.

I'm looking for some solution that will `fopen` and `fwrite` this data to the file.

Any ideas on how to accomplish that or is there any library that can do this?

Comment: The problem with any Metadata approach will probably be that it'll be lost when the thief re-encodes the video. Not sure how useful it'd be

Comment: Most of the thief's does not reencode the video. They just share.

Comment: Fair enough. It's a valid question.

Answer (score 0):

As Pekka mentioned, inserting meta data won't help you fight piracy. The minute the pirate re-encodes the file, the meta data is lost. In addition, there is software (e.g. [TigoTago](http://tigotago.com/assets/images/pr0xy/index.php)) which edits meta-data.

A better approach would be to:

1. Don't allow downloads. Instead, use encrypted streaming.
2. Allow downloads, but chase down the pirated content; whenever you find the videos on Rapidshare and other file sharing sites, file a complaint.

Because *punishing the pirate* won't do much. They'll just sign up again with a different name, a different email, and a different prepaid credit card.

If you're still unsure about it; take a look at iTunes. The file which you download cannot be played on any computer which is not authorized (if the file is protected). But, the minute a user converts the file or re-encodes it, the file can be played any where on anything.

*edit*

And anyways, most pirate shares and torrents are uploaded as MKV or AVI. So most likely, the pirates will be converting and re-encoding it before they upload it; rendering the metadata useless.

Comment: We will loose real paying members if we opt to streaming only. Most of the users do not reencode the video, they just share it. We already file a DMCA and have a person to do this job full time. But being hard when the person sharing still have access to our sites. If we block their account, they can signup using a prepaid card, but we will earn on that resign up and I think they will get tired and move on to another site.